# ->Transitions->

Tags: word, knowledge, cipher, crosswords

Here is a crossword to solve; the yellow squares hold a relevant word.
Online tools will be useful/needed.

[image: grid]

[image: across]

[image: down]

*partial text transcription:*

```
> ACROSS
> 1. Distance to the Star Wars’ g                            ?
> 3. Bacon soBAABBBAAAAAAABAAABAA
> 10. A possJAPC RBQC DKN SGC CREKFJRH SGBS 0BT KRP3 VTCF JR 6WB BRF YZB
> 12. Mistakes flagged for corr                           
> 15. Wonder at;                                      
> 18. Fin5   3 15 6 6 5 5
> 21. Downy se
> 23. What those using 24D’s cipher mig….  -     .-..   .-  -.-.  -.-  
> 25. Makes difficult to see, like a fence, PAEHPRS
> 26. That which is coming int---    -…  .  ..  -.  --.
> 27. Items used in 4D’
> 29. Chaos’ op
> 30. Things in a col .-..  .  -.-.  -  ..  ---  -.
> 32. Forerunner
> 33. Country on Namibia’s northe 
> 35. A posTJAPC RBQC DKN SGC CREKFJRH SGBS 0BT KRP3 VTCF JR 6WB BRF YZB 
> 42. Apollo-13 eATVARRE?
> 43. 504, in 16D’F AHZRENYF

> DOWN
> 1. Nine, in 16D’ 
> 2. A small, squali 
> 3. Color made by scrambling LLOEYW NAD ORNBW
> 4. Extrasensory perception, foAr  KOPArCa
> 5. Aegean, ELPMAXE ROF
> 6. Columbus’ ship, ATNAS HTIW
> 7. Container for mixed USTN RO OOIECKS
> 8. OpPOSITE OF 13D 
> 9. Color made by scrambling LLOEYW NAD ORNBW
> 11. Large box 4 HAULING 1DERFUL THINGS, LOL 
> 13. Very s --  .-  .-..  .-.. 
> 14. Arrangements of pentom ..  -.  ---  .  ...
> 15. Like-minded bod 
> 16. Complex and involved, like thiXIX  XVI XXI XXVI XXVI XII V
> 17. Self-m  
> 19. Burner use 
> 20. Add into a collection, as in SQL, or add 3 rails to a FEECN
> 22. Best or moFG SNIBENOYR
> 23. Prisoner’s view; prison .  …..  …. ..  ‘ ….  ...    .  ….  .  …..  ….  …  ..  ….  ….  ..  .  …..?
> 24. Peninsula known for it 
> 28. Inclin 
> 31. Terms of Servi  
> 32. Thirteen snBJ ZBAFGREF?
> 34. Two-legTRQ PERNGHER
> 35. Tolkien ERUTAERC EERT
> 36. ___thermal enBArNMn
> 37. AnsweR TO 7D
> 38. Bone taken MADA MORF
> 39. Hazy LondON FEATURE
> 40. Tangle or bash intL Z GSRXP NZHH LI IFT
> 41. In 4D’s cipher, it’s num2 5 18   20 23 5 14 20 25
```

Comment: yep, for me it did. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously, the back halves of the clues have all been encoded somehow.

> Several clues hide references to their encodings inside them. Below, I've bolded the decoded parts of the clue, and underlined any hints towards the cipher.
>
>  [image: Across clues, decoded]
>  [image: Down clues, decoded]
>
>  There are some nonstandard ciphers in there:
>  "remove verticals" isn't really a cipher, because it's not reversible. Those clues have you remove all vertical bars from them.
>  "anagram" is similarly not a cipher.
>  "sideways" just has all letters tilted on their sides.
>  "identity" is the transformation that does nothing at all - the plaintext is the same as the ciphertext.
>
>  And of course, there's the one used in 10A and 35A, which look to be the same clue. It doesn't appear to be a well-known cipher, but you can bruteforce it as a cryptogram to get the clue:
>
>  10. A poss**ible name for the encoding that was only used in 10A and 35A**

## Filling the grid

> Some entries don't fit in the grid in the natural way. So what do you do?
>  It turns out you can only fill the grid *by encoding each answer in its corresponding clue's cipher*. The result of this is shown here:
>
>  [image: grid filled]
>
>  To fill 10A and 35A, you need to use crossing letters (converting them back before trying to fill in the blanks). 10A turns out to be **`SUBSTITUTION CIPHER`**, and 35A turns out to be **`STRAIGHTS AND CURVES`**. The cipher for those clues is generated by lining up all the characters written with only straight lines, and all the ones that have a curved line somewhere:
>   `AEFHIKLMNTVWXYZ147`
>   `BCDGJOPQRSU0235689`
>
>  Then, each letter is replaced with its partner in the above two lines.
>
>  The highlighted letters, when decoded according to the ciphers from their Across clues, spell the answer: **ENCRYPTION**.

Comment: All correct so far!

Comment: rot13(rirel fgenvtug yrggre vf fjnccrq jvgu n pheirq yrggre) so maybe rot13(FGENVTUGFNAQPHEIRF)

Comment: @cap yep! The mystery cipher, which can be generated end to end (though not required here) has been my all time favorite go-to cipher ever since I created it as a kid, so I thought it'd be fun to share it in here. It is based on the classic puzzle but I have no idea if others have used the cipher.

Comment: @Amoz, nice, I like it. This is an awesome puzzle. But wait, you're rot13(abg n xvq nalzber?!)

Comment: @cap Ah, nice! Edited in, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I haven't worked out how to fill out the whole grid yet, but here's what I have for all of the decoded clues, if it helps save anyone some time:

**Across:**

> 1 DISTANCE TO THE STAR WARS GALAXY
>  3 BACON SOURCE
>  10 A POSSIBLE NAME FOR THE ENCODING THAT WAS ONLY USED IN 10A AND 35A
>  12 MISTAKES FLAGGED FOR CORRECTION
>  15 WONDER AT; COMICS PUBLISHER
>  18 FINE COFFEE
>  21 DOWNY SEA DUCK
>  23 WHAT THOSE USING 24D'S CIPHER MIGHT LACK
>  25 MAKES DIFFICULT TO SEE, LIKE A FENCE, PERHAPS
>  26 THAT WHICH IS COMING INTO BEING
>  27 ITEMS USED IN 4D'S CIPHER
>  29 CHAOS' OPPOSITE
>  30 THINGS IN A COLLECTION
>  32 FORERUNNERS OF EFFECTS
>  33 COUNTRY ON NAMIBIA'S NORTHERN SIDE
>  35 A POSSIBLE NAME FOR THE ENCODING THAT WAS ONLY USED IN 10A AND 35A
>  42 APOLLO-13 ENGINEER?
>  43 504 IN 16D'S NUMERALS

**Down:**

> 1 NINE, IN 16D'S NUMERALS
>  2 A SMALL SQUALID DWELLING
>  3 COLOR MADE BY SCRAMBLING YELLOW AND BROWN
>  4 EXTRASENSORY PERCEPTION, FOR SHORT
>  5 AEGEAN, FOR EXAMPLE
>  6 COLUMBUS' SHIP, WITH SANTA
>  7 CONTAINER FOR MIXED NUTS OR COOKIES
>  8 OPPOSITE OF 13D
>  9 COLOR MADE BY SCRAMBLING YELLOW AND BROWN
>  11 LARGE BOX FOR HAULING WONDERFUL THINGS LOL
>  13 VERY SMALL
>  14 ARRANGEMENTS OF PENTOMINOES
>  15 LIKE-MINDED BODY OF PEOPLE
>  16 COMPLEX AND INVOLVED, LIKE THIS PUZZLE
>  17 SELF-MEASUREMENT
>  19 BURNER USED TO HEAT 27A
>  20 ADD INTO A COLLECTION, AS IN SQL, OR ADD 3 RAILS TO A FENCE
>  22 BEST OR MOST FAVORABLE
>  23 PRISONER'S VIEW; PRISONER'S DESIRE
>  24 PENINSULA KNOWN FOR ITS NIGHTS
>  28 INCLINED PLANE
>  31 TERMS OF SERVICE, FOR SHORT
>  32 THIRTEEN SNOW MONSTERS?
>  34 TWO-LEGGED CREATURE
>  35 TOLKIEN TREE CREATURE
>  36 ___THERMAL ENERGY
>  37 ANSWER TO 7D
>  38 BONE TAKEN FROM ADAM
>  39 HAZY LONDON FEATURE
>  40 TANGLE OR BASH INTO A THICK MASS OR RUG
>  41 IN 4D'S CIPHER, ITS NUMBER TWENTY